# Lufthansa: personal item or not?

Tags: luggage, lufthansa

My employer booked me an international flight (in economy class) with Lufthansa, and I found those two links when looking up my luggage allowance:

https://www.lufthansa.com/de/en/Carry-on-baggage

https://www.lufthansa.com/de/en/Free-baggage-rules

The first one mentions only the carry-on, specifying that a personal item (ie laptop etc.) is allowed on top of the carry-on(s) included in the ticket.

The second one, on the other hand, mentions the checked-in luggage and the carry-on, but makes no mention of the personal item.

Does anyone knows if I can basically take three items (checked-in, carry-on and personal item)?

Thanks!

Comment: Lufthansa seems to be very relaxed on this policy, contrary to budget lines. I often take LH flights within EU with a small backpack and carry-on baggage - no problems encountered. Once I had these items and an A3 poster tube with me - no problems as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can take personal item in addition to the other carry on per https://www.lufthansa.com/us/en/Carry-on-baggage . I certainly have never seen an issue with that.

This may not apply to an "Economy Light" fare, in which case they may be more strict.

Please keep in mind that the carry on has an 8kg weight restriction which they tend to enforce. Most "regular" US sized roll-a-boards are heavier than that when packed full, so make sure you weigh before heading to the airport.

Answer (score 2):

Most travelers take a laptop (or similar) bag AND the carry-on baggage, just as the less restrictive page says:

https://www.lufthansa.com/de/en/Carry-on-baggage

Just make sure your carry-on weights less than 8kg to avoid any trouble with it.

If you keep any concerns, you may take a screenshot of the page, or even print it. I' am sure you will not have any issues with your laptop, but you will have a good point to discuss in case you're asked to pay.